# Problem with display multiple Toast in order one after another

Tags: android, toast

sorry for my bad English.
i want show two toast in order, in other word when first toast duration is over second toast appear.
this is my code :

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Toast1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Toast.makeText(this, "Toast2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

but only second toast message will appear. i think when show method of second toast will execute it will cancel previous toast (first toast)

I solved my problem with this code :

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Toast1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Handler handler =new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Toast2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    },1000);
```

but is there any easier solution?

Comment: What if I have to show same toast one after another ? For example, during Signin, when user press on Submit without entering any data : "Username required".. This toast is overlapping one on another. What If I have to display it one after another ?

Comment: Consider using a Snackbar for one of the messages, oftentimes, it could be more appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but only second toast message will appear. i think when show method of
>   second toast will execute it will cancel previous toast (first toast)

When you call `show` method, it will put into message queue of UI thread, and the Toast will be shown in order. But you put two Toast at the same time, the latter will overlap the former.

> i want show two toast in order, in other word when first toast
>   duration is over second toast appear.

From [Toast duration](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.3_r2/services/java/com/android/server/NotificationManagerService.java)

```
private static final int LONG_DELAY = 3500; // 3.5 seconds 
private static final int SHORT_DELAY = 2000; // 2 seconds
```

To make the second toast display after duration of the first one, change your code to

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Toast1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Toast2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}, 2000);
```

> but is there any easier solution?

Using Handler is the easy and simple solution to achieve your task.

Comment: What if I have to show same toast one after another ? For example, during Signin, when user press on Submit without entering any data : "Username required".. This toast is overlapping one on another. What If I have to display it one after another ?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to achieve it

- Method 1: Use Thread as you used but use timer and execute one by
  one
- Method 2: Use any Loop, For Example use For Loop

Comment: What if I have to show same toast one after another ? For example, during Signin, when user press on Submit without entering any data : "Username required".. This toast is overlapping one on another. What If I have to display it one after another ?

Comment: For method 2 to work, you would have to have a Delay in the loop. Otherwise, the second toast will happen immediately; first toast won't be seen. (If put a delay in loop, then must be on background thread. You mightt then need to invoke toast on UI thread.)

Answer (score 2):

Other solution is to use AlertDialog

`createDialog().show();`

with two methods createDialog() and continueDialog()

```
public AlertDialog createDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Toast1")
            .setPositiveButton("Next",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            continueDialog().show();
                        }
                    });
    return builder.create();
}

public AlertDialog continueDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Toast2")
            .setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    });
    return builder.create();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution in Kotlin using Coroutines. It works for me because I want to see all messages for their stipulated durations, but the order of messages doesn't really matter.

### Things to note

- Each new message waits for the previous toast to finish being shown
- Multiple messages won't be shown at the same time because `isToasting` is a volatile variable (acting as a key).
- Note for debugging: Toasts may be shown out of order if there is more than one message waiting in the queue.

```kotlin
@Volatile
private var isToasting = false

CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
    // Wait for key to be released
    while (isToasting) {
        delay(500)
    }

    isToasting = true // Retrieve the key
    withContext(Main) {
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        // Approximate the time taken for the toast to finish showing
        withContext(IO) {
            delay(2500) // Length of Toast.LENGTH_SHORT + 500ms
            isToasting = false // Release key
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you :

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Show toast 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                sleep(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); // sleep the time first toast is being shown
                Toast.makeText(this, "Show toast 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: What if I have to show same toast one after another ? For example, during Signin, when user press on Submit without entering any data : "Username required".. This toast is overlapping one on another. What If I have to display it one after another ?